# Bootstrap row dissapearing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that contains several rows, but one of them is disappearing.

The source code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row"><!--works fine-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2"><!--this div contains thing2-->
        <h1>thing1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"><!--this row dissapears-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"><!--this div is gone-->
            <h1>thing2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"><!--works fine-->
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I can tell this code looks fine, but this is what it turns into when it gets displayed.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row"><!--works fine-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2"><!--this div contains thing2-->
        <h1>thing1</h1>
        <h1>thing2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"><!--works fine-->
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This makes thing1 and thing2 appear together and not on their own row, and I have no idea why.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your error. Works just fine for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, everything seems to work fine, but have you noticed that you have more than 12 columns per row? It may be a clearfix problem.

Comment: Also if your col-md and col-lg are going to be the same as sm, you don't need to specify them since col-sm will apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to its breakpoint size.

Comment: It seems like you didn't close tags in example, where you had this issue. So just check html tags

Comment: Try validating your code https://validator.w3.org/. There could be a quote or unclosed div further up that causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was not bootstrap at all. Thanks everyone for mentioning you can't reproduce it, made me dig deeper. The issue turns out to be what was in the div. It was an angular select element with a self closing tag. Changing it to a normal closing tag fixed everything. I excluded it because I thought it was not important and didn't verify before posting.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"><!--works fine-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2"><!--this div contains thing2-->
        <h1>thing1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><!--this row dissapears-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"><!--this div is gone-->
        <h1>Row that disappears.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><!--works fine-->
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        Last Row
      </div>
    </div>
```

The code doesn't seem to have any problem @Trevor. I just implemented it and it works well according to me. Let me know if i have misinterpreted your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine. please check your css file or bootstrap library. 
please use bootstrap cdn [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css).